# custom cursor img not dissapearing outside of box on mouseleave event

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a custom cursor image so it can replace my actual cursor in certain section. What i would like to achieve is to show the image when inside the section and make it disappear when section is left. I managed to display it correctly while being in the section but going outside does not hide it. What am I doing wrong?

```js
const box = document.querySelector(".box");

const customCursor = document.createElement("img");

customCursor.style.width = "175px";
customCursor.style.height = "175px";
customCursor.style.position = "absolute";
customCursor.src = "https://picsum.photos/175";
customCursor.style.display = "none";

box.appendChild(customCursor);

box.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  customCursor.style.display = "block";
  customCursor.style.left = `${e.pageX - customCursor.width / 2}px`;
  customCursor.style.top = `${e.pageY - customCursor.height / 2}px`;
});

box.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
  customCursor.style.display = "none";
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  cursor: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5rem;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Leaving a sandbox link as well - https://codesandbox.io/s/javascript-forked-6v9rcm?file=/src/index.js

Comment: You've set up the cursor image as a child of the box. The criteria you've set up is technically "when the mouse leaves the box or any of its descendant boxes". When the cursor image shows under the mouse, mouse events are sent to the cursor and then cascade up the hierarchy to the box. Since the cursor is always under the mouse, the cursor, technically, never leaves the box. I think adding the CSS `pointer-event: none;` to the cursor element might fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [Ouroborus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/367865/ouroborus) comment

You have to add `pointer-events: none` to your img

```js
const box = document.querySelector(".box");

const customCursor = document.createElement("img");

customCursor.style.pointerEvents = "none";
customCursor.style.width = "175px";
customCursor.style.height = "175px";
customCursor.style.position = "absolute";
customCursor.src = "https://picsum.photos/175";
customCursor.style.display = "none";

box.appendChild(customCursor);

box.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  customCursor.style.display = "block";
  customCursor.style.left = `${e.pageX - customCursor.width / 2}px`;
  customCursor.style.top = `${e.pageY - customCursor.height / 2}px`;
});

box.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
  customCursor.style.display = "none";
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  cursor: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5rem;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue can be resolved by changing your events listeners. If you use mouseover and mouseout you'll have a better time.

```js
const box = document.querySelector(".box");

const customCursor = document.createElement("img");

customCursor.style.width = "175px";
customCursor.style.height = "175px";
customCursor.style.position = "absolute";
customCursor.src = "https://picsum.photos/175";
customCursor.style.display = "none";

box.appendChild(customCursor);

box.addEventListener("mouseover", (e) => {
  customCursor.style.display = "block";
  customCursor.style.left = `${e.pageX - customCursor.width / 2}px`;
  customCursor.style.top = `${e.pageY - customCursor.height / 2}px`;
});

box.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
  customCursor.style.display = "none";
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  cursor: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5rem;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Notice that it now jumps instead of moving smoothly